# Iferror/Index/Match formula that was formerly working now returns all False results despite values existing on target sheet

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I wrote a macro some time ago to search for values from one spreadsheet (Data) on another spreadsheet (Sheet1), then pull the value from the cell 2 columns to the left of where the result was found on Sheet1. It was working great, but something seems to have changed(???) and it's now returning all "False" results, despite the fact that the values certainly exist in both spreadsheets.

It searches for the values in Column C on the first worksheet on the second sheet (always called Sheet1)

I can provide the spreadsheets in question for any testing.
My annotated code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Sub GroupFileNameFix()
'
' GroupFileNameFix Macro

'define variable types
Dim strFormula As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

'on Data sheet
With ActiveSheet
' determines last row on spreadsheet and saves value to variable "LastRow"
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   'sets variable "strFormula" as what we want to autofill, grabbing group filenames
strFormula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!RC[-3],(MATCH(RC[1],Sheet1!C[-1],0))),""False"")"
'inserts column "GroupFileName" as column D
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GroupFileName"
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
' Fills cell D2 and then autofills column D to end of spreadsheet
Range("D2:D2").Select
.Range("D2:D2").Formula = strFormula
.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FillDown
End With
'Commit formula to text and replace "png" with "jpg"
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Replace What:="png", Replacement:="jpg", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: So all this code, for what essentially boils down to "Why does `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!RC[-3],(MATCH(RC[1],Sheet1!C[-1],0))),"False")` return FALSE?" ...try evaluating the function in Excel, your `Index/Match` is throwing an error. FWIW I would avoid R1C1 notation.

Comment: "It searches for the values in Column C on the first worksheet on the second sheet (always called Sheet1)".  Unless I am reading your code wrong, your `MATCH(RC[1],Sheet1!C[-1],0)` is trying to match the value in column E of the active sheet, with the values in column C of Sheet1.  Is that what your sentence is saying?

Comment: Why are you selecting ranges that you can directly call? Or making a cell formula equal ro a string?
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GroupFileName" 
 Should be  Range("D1").value = "GroupFileName"

Comment: mooseman - Thank you, I've made that change.

YowE3K - Good catch. Changing that "RC[1]" to "RC[-1]" (now referencing the intended cell in Column C) doesn't have any effect on the result however.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, since you are always putting the formula in the same column, this worked for me.

```
With ActiveSheet
 strFormula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A2,(MATCH(E2,Sheet1!C:C,0))),""False"")"
 'inserts column "GroupFileName" as column D
 Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Range("D1").Value = "GroupFileName"
 Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
 ' Fills cell D2 and then autofills column D to end of spreadsheet
 .Range("D2").Formula = strFormula
 .Range("D2:D" & LastRow).FillDown
End With
```

Comment: I decided to strip this down to just the formula and work backwards from that simpler starting point. 

This is a ridiculously simple question, I realize, but I can't figure out how to get this formula to reference the cell two columns to the left of the result it finds. In the formula below, it's returning the value two rows above the result. I understand that "-2" in this context means two rows above, but what would be the syntax for two columns to the left in this formula?

    =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C$2:C$2000, MATCH($C2,Sheet1!C$2:C$2000,0))-2),"False")

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so this ended up being a lot simpler than I was making it. I got caught up in trying to automate this with a macro, when a simple paste formula & autofill workflow is just as easy. The formula below works perfectly.

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$2000,(MATCH($C2,Sheet1!C$2:C$2000,0))),"False")